# What is the 15 point spacing on the left of table view cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have seen various posts on this topic.

I want to remove this spacing because I'm programmatically setting my constraints and when I constrain my view to the left of a cell there is an added 15 points.

The solutions that I have seen are not very good.

For example they change the tableView's inset to be -15 on the left. 
This moves the whole table view cell 15 points to the left leaving a right gap on the right.

Also, I personally have subtracted 15 from my constraints. 
This isn't a good solution because this value can change in the future.

I don't understand how a content inset of (0,0,0,0) still has a 15 point indentation on the left. 
How can we completely remove this ?

Update:

Now I'm subtracting `separatorInset.left` from my constraints when needed. This avoids hardcoding values but I'm still baffled at how confusing this topic is.

Example constraint

```
// If I remove separatorInset.left there will be an added 15 point padding on the left
let leading = statusButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: (contentView.frame.width*0.09) - separatorInset.left)
```

Comment: How are you setting up your constraints programmatically? I have created table view's programmatically and I have never seen this 15 px. Just curious to see how you are doing it.

Comment: @gwinyai I will add an example

Comment: And if you try leadingAnchor instead of leftAnchor, is this 15 px still there?

Comment: @gwinyai yes, I tried that along with NSLayoutConstraint(....

Comment: @gwinyai wait, I switched from a UIButton to a UIImageView and the problem went away. I think the image in the button was not updating according to the constraints of the button therefore there was empty space that I thought was the 15 points. The ImageView updates the image automatically so the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the storyboard you can change the default indentation. Just choose the "Custom insets". See the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove edge insets programmatically, here is the swift 3 collectionview override func:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
```